# Are there any Perfectly Abundant Numbers?

Tags: proof-verification, perfect-numbers

Define a *Perfectly Abundant Number* as a number with the property:
$$
x : \sigma(x) = 2x + 1,
$$

where $\sigma$ is the sum of the factors of $x$, including itself.  In other words, $x$ isn't a perfect number because the sum of its proper factors (not including $x$) is one greater than itself, making it Abundant.  However, it is *almost* perfect because it differs by only one.  Are the there any such number.  In a brute force search with sage I didn't find any less than $10^6$.  Is there a mathematical proof that no such number exists?

Comment: You can narrow your search to numbers of the form $2^nk^2$ with $k$ odd.  This is because $\sigma(x)$ is multiplicative.  If there is a factor $p^m$ with $p$ and odd prime and the maximal power of $p$ dividing the number $m$ odd, we have $\sigma(p^m)=1+p+p^2+\dots p^m$, which is even and $\sigma(x)=\sigma(p^m)\sigma(x/p^m)$ is also even.

Comment: There are no such numbers known, nor is there a proof known that there are none. I believe the name quasiperfect has been used.

Comment: Found it, had the right name, [Wikipedia of course.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the formula $pf(p^2 n) = (p + 1) pf(p n) - p\times pf(n)$ for any prime $p$ and $pf(p n) = (p + 1) pf(n) + n$ when $p$ is a prime and not a factor of $n$.  I was just too lazy to code that time saver, and where pf is the sum of all prime factors.  But thanks for the advice, I may try change it to that for larger values in the large number space of Python and sorry I didn't call them Quasiperfect but thanks André for setting me straight!